# PHP substr use .length as param?

Tags: php

```
$link = '/item/123456';
$num = substr($link,0,$link->length);
```

Above code won't work why? I want to assign 123456 to $num. I used the same logic in JS it work but not in PHP? I'm new to PHP.

Comment: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" < seems clear to me why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, [`strlen()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is the method to get the string length:

```
$link = '/item/123456';
$num = substr($link, 0, strlen($link));
```

If you have the multibyte extension installed ([mbstring](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php)), it is better to use `mb_*` functions as they are compatible with strings of different encodings such as Unicode:

```
$link = '/item/123456';
$num = mb_substr($link, 0, mb_strlen($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

That no PHP syntax and you should get an error.

use `strlen` for that

```
$num = substr($link,0,strlen($link));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php